# C++ DLL Injector not working

Tags: c++, dll

I'm coding a DLL injector in c++, but it's simply not working. So all I wanna do is just inject my own DLL which should open a Message Box that says: "Hello" into a dummy program, but nothing is happening. I thought that it could be the handle, but reading and writing memory just works fine. I also tried other varients than the below shown code, but nothing worked for me, so I hope that's enough information to start with, if not just tell me and here's the code thanks already:

```
BOOL Inject(LPCSTR DllPath, HANDLE hProc) {
    LPVOID pDllPath = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, strlen(DllPath) + 1, 
    MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    bool written = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pDllPath, DllPath, 
    strlen(DllPath) + 1, 0);

    HANDLE hLoadThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0,
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"),
        "LoadLibraryA"), pDllPath, 0, 0);

    std::cout << pDllPath << std::endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(hLoadThread, INFINITE);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pDllPath, strlen(DllPath) + 1, MEM_RELEASE);
    return written;
}
```

Comment: "It's just not working" is not an acceptable description of the problem. What are we supposed to do with that level of information? What are you trying to do? What happens when you try it? What did you want to happen instead? All we have to go on to deduce what you want to do is an out-of-context function that, by your own admission, _does not do that thing_! What steps have you taken so far? Where did you "hear" that "it" could be the compiler, and what is "it"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and yeah you're right. So I want to inject a DLL into a dummy program and I'm trying it with the method you can see up there ^ the handle is ok because I can write and read memory out of the process and it even returns me that I've written the path into the program but nothing happens. My DLL should open a Message Box which says: "Hello". So I tried other variants of the DLL Injection but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually sorry guys, I'll close this question, but it was the convertation from a normal std::string to LPCSTR which caused the problem and not the actual injector. So yeah, but if someone of you got the same problem. In my case it worked when I used the myString.c_str(); when calling the function for example: Inject(dllPath.c_str(), hProcess); When I was trying to "save" the LPCSTR earlier and than call it for example:

```
LPCSTR dllPath;
dllPath = sDllPath.c_str();

Inject(dllPath, hProcess);
```

it didn't work, but yeah I found a way so sorry for this post.